# Model binding for the multiple partial views in dotnet core

Tags: model-view-controller, .net-core, imodelbinder

I want to design common model binding using one common partial view and other multiple partial views based on the model type with different model binding.

I have one base Dialog Model and two derived models.

```
public class DialogModel
{
    public int DialogType { get; set; }

    public string ViewName { get; set; }
}

public class DialogModel1: DialogModel
{

}

public class DialogModel2: DialogModel
{

}
```

I have one action method and I am posting JSON data based on model type.

```
public IActionResult OpenDialog(DialogModel model)
    {
        string view = string.Empty;
        switch (model.DialogType)
        {
            case 1:
                model.View = "MyDialogPartialView1";

                DialogModel1 model1 = (DialogModel1)model;
                //mode1 properties set;

                view = this.RenderViewAsync("CommonDialogPartialView", model1, true).Result;

                break;
            case 2:
                model.View = "MyDialogPartialView2";

                DialogModel2 model2 = (DialogModel2)model;
                //mode2 properties set;

                view = this.RenderViewAsync("CommonDialogPartialView", model2, true).Result;

                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        return new JsonResult(new { view });
    }
```

I am setting the view name of partial view based on dialog type and casting into the related model and rendering the common partial view "CommonDialogPartialView" and returning the response text.

I am appending this response text in the client-side.

My common partial view HTML.

```
    @model ChurchPharmacy3.Models.DialogModel

<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
    <div class="modal-content" id="popup_body">
        <div class="modal-header bg-info">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">@Model.Title</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            @await Html.PartialAsync(Model.View)
            <!--This partial view can be "MyDialogPartialView1" or "MyDialogPartialView2" -->
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer bg-light">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Cancel</button>

            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Ok</button>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

This common partial view getting model of DialogModel and I am rendering another partial view from the common partial view based on view name.

here is my partial view for Dialog type 1.

```
 @model ChurchPharmacy3.Models.DialogModel1
<!--Model of DialogModel1-->
```

and same for the partial view for Dialog type 2.

```
@model ChurchPharmacy3.Models.DialogModel2
<!--Model of DialogModel1-->
```

When I am casting the model into DialogModel1 or DialogModel2, it throws an exception.

Answer (score 0):

I have used IModelBinder and able to fix the above issue.

Here is the solution for the above issue.

```
public class DialogModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));

        JObject jObject = null;
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(bindingContext.ActionContext.HttpContext.Request.Body))
        {
            using (var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(reader))
            {
                jObject = JObject.LoadAsync(jsonReader).Result;
            }
        }
        var modelType = (int)jObject.SelectToken("dialogType");

        if (modelType == (byte)DialogType.Dialog1)
        {
            var obj = DeserializeObject<Dialog1>(jObject.ToString());
            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(obj);
        }
        if (modelType == (byte)DialogType.Dialog1)
        {
            var obj = DeserializeObject<Dialog2>(jObject.ToString());
            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(obj);
        }
        else
        {
            var obj = DeserializeObject<DialogModel>(jObject.ToString());
            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(obj);
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private static T DeserializeObject<T>(string json)
    {
        return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json, new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            TypeNameHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.TypeNameHandling.Auto
        });
    }

}
```